# JSON a list Flask

Tags: python, json

I want to send this list as JSON in the Flask framework.

I fetched something from my DB and I have this here as my list:

```
[('GG',)]
```

How do I send it to JSON?

```
@app.route('/gt', methods=['GET'])
def gt():
    logged_in_email = session['auth']
    if not logged_in_email:
        return "Nothing"
    else:
        r = todo.retrieve_todo(logged_in_email)
        print(r)
        print(type(r))
        return r
```

This doesn't work, I tried `json.loads` but that expects a string and I have a list?

Answer (score 1):

Using `jsonify` you can return json result easily.

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/gt', methods=['GET'])
def gt():
    logged_in_email = session['auth']
    if not logged_in_email:
        return "Nothing"
    else:
        r = todo.retrieve_todo(logged_in_email)
        return jsonify(r=r)
```

Or if you want to return `str`, use `json.dumps`.
`json.loads` converts `str` to `list` or `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this....

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def json_sample():
    return jsonify([1, 2, "test"])
```